# SAMSUNG 4GB DDR3 Laptop RAM fake or genuine?

Tags: laptop, memory, ddr3

Today, I purchased Samsung Laptop Ram 4GB DDR3.
Three serial numbers printed on the Chip.

1. 837, where 8=2018, and 37=37th week of the year 2018.
2. HCH9, where C=1.5V, and H9=1333 (667) MHz.
3. K4B2G0846D which contains all information about the module organization.

Also, the following data were established by CPUZID.
Part Number M471B5273BHO-CKO, and its Serial Number is also shown.

Now, on cross checking all data of the above 2 cases using the Samsung RAM DECODER Chart, many variations were encountered.

1. As per the chart and as per the part number M471B5273BHO-CKO, I should get (KO=1600MHz) whereas chip has labelled HCH9 where H9=1333MHz.
   Now, I'm confused whether part number is wrong or not.
2. As per the SEC chart and as per the "SEC 837" printed on the chip, I should get manufacturing date be "37 week of 2018". However, in contrast, CPUID shows "26 week of 21"
   Again, I'm now confused which production date is correct?

Please some one enlighten me whether this RAM module is genuine or not?
Also, why CPUID shows information which does not corresponds to the labels printed on the CHIPS.
(I have tested another same module, and yes CPUID shows correct info with the labels on CHIPS.)

[FULL PHOTOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAv0P.jpg)

Comment: Did you check with the company where you purchased the memory?  Return it if you do not believe them and purchase from Samsung directly.

Comment: The manufacture date absolutely is NOT in 2021.  DDR3 is not mass produced at this time.

Answer (score 0):

It has been purchased a SODIMM module with 16 DRAM ICs each marked K4B2G0846D HCH9 (meaning 2Gibit DDR3 DRAM IC organized as 256MiByte, rated for 667MHz clock thus transfer rate twice that), and a smaller Serial Presence Detect IC. Windows utilities can't read from DRAM ICs. At best they reads the SPD (probably, indirectly). It reports a M471B52738H0-CK0 part number, which is that of a Samsung DDR3 SODIMM module rated PC3-12800.

It's reported a difference in date codes between ICs and SPD content. Some is normal, but 2 years and 41 weeks as reported would be suspicious: Samsung is not known for stockpiling ICs that long. With such difference in date (that I can't confirm) I would not trust the module to be a genuine Samsung one in its original state.

Even more worrying: although the [photo of the module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAv0P.jpg) is not very good, and most of the sticker is hidden: the PCB does not look like I'd expect a Samsung SODIMM to be; nor does what I can see of the sticker. [Here](https://www.cdiscount.com/pdt2/1/1/0/1/700x700/sam3665541002110/rw/barrette-memoire-4go-ram-ddr3-samsung-m471b5273ch0.jpg) is how I believe is a genuine Samsung DDR3 SODIMM model M471B52738H0-CK0 (but, there could be several variations). Unfortunately, we are not looking at the same side.

And the nail in the coffin: the ICs are marked K4B2G0846D HCH9, which implies DDR3-1333 (9-9-9). That's consistent with PC3-10700 @667MHz clock shon by the Windows utility (since 667×2≈1333, 1333×8≈10700). But M471B52738H0-CK0 presumably in the SPD chip is the reference of a PC3-12800 Samsung Module, and I strongly expect Samsung would not put DDR3-1333 ICs on that, only DDR3-1600 or better.

So this is not a Samsung-made or Samsung-sanctioned SODIMM. It could have been made by another manufacturer, perhaps recycled with a Samsung part number in the SPD, or even built from "pulled-up" parts (either of which would explain the discrepancy of date code). There's uncertainty about how the PCB design was validated, and how the module was tested. In any case, I would not use it at faster than 667MHz clock (aka DDR3-1333, aka PC3-10600, PC3-10666, PC3-10700) with 9-9-9 timing.

Independently: if the module is installed on a Windows machine, I'd try the command

```
wmic MemoryChip get BankLabel, ConfiguredClockSpeed, Manufacturer, PartNumber, Speed, SerialNumber
```

Note: it's a bit unclear when the question refers to an integrated circuit (also known as IC or chip) and when it refers to a module (a printed circuit board with ICs soldered on it). This answer uses the standard vocabulary.